# Where to see the Dockerfile for a docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

Is there a way to see the Dockerfile that generated an image I downloaded, to use as a template for my own docker images?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use

```
docker history --no-trunc IMAGE_NAME_OR_ID
```

This will show all commands run in the image building process in reverse order. It's not exactly a Dockerfile, but you can find all essential content.