# Viewing Original Docker Build Commands for a Running Container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I accidentally deleted the Docker file for a container that is still running.
Is there a way to view how the container was originally built?

Answer (score 1):

If you copied all your files at build time and aren't `.dockerignore`-ing Dockerfile, you might get lucky and be able to find it in the container. You can use `docker exec {CONTAINER_NAME/ID} ls -al` or similar to do a quick check (you might need to change which directory based on where the files were copied and what the default working directory is).

Otherwise you can try `docker history ...` or use a reverse-compile tool, see [Docker: Reverse Engineering of an Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48228275/docker-reverse-engineering-of-an-image)