# How to download Dockerfile from Docker Hub?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

In docker hub I can see the Dockerfile for each image.

How can I download the Dockerfile without copying each line manually?

Comment: Earlier some users added links to the Dockerfile in overview, but nowadays very few does. A good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43310650/536262

Comment: @MortenB That answer is a good one but a bit outdated. In fact, now, using the `docker history` command is far better.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot see the Dockerfile from Docker Hub, unless the maintainer add it. Many Docker hub repos add the GitHub link to point the Dockerfile but this is up to the maintaner.

What you can do to see the dockerfile is:

1. pull the Docker image with `docker pull <image-name>`
2. `docker history <image-name>`

From the `docker history` command, the first line indicates the parent docker image and in the following lines you can see all the steps used to compose the final image.